# Как из фрагмента закрыть или удалить етот же фрагмент в активити?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Я пробовал так : ((MainActivity)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this);

Но так ошибка.

Comment: Ошибку-то покажите.

Comment: Inconvertible types; cannot cast int

Answer (score 1):

> remove (android.support v4.app.Fragmernt) in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (anonimus android.view.View.onclicklistener)

Если вы это сделали внутри лиснера, то this ссылается не на ваш Fragment, а на экземпляр анонимного класса, которым является ваш лиснер. Вам нужно

```
....remove(YorFragment.this)
```

Comment: После етого вторая ошибка : Inconvertible types; cannot cast int

Comment: Ох. А со скобочками все хорошо?

Comment: нет, с  '' - too many characters in character literal

Comment: а с "" - in FragmentTransaction cannot be  applied to (java.land.string)

Comment: Покажите полную строку.

Comment: Уже исправил. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Что за ошибка, вы не пишете, но точно забыт `.commit()` в конце этого выражения.

Comment: remove (android.support v4.app.Fragmernt) in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (anonimus android.view.View.onclicklistener)